# Deleting a section from a UITableView. NSIndexSet parameter?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

I am trying to delete a section in a table after I have verified it has no more rows, but I am not sure what I am supposed to pass to it for the NSIndexSet parameter. Here is a code snippet I am using it in:

```
        public override void CommitEditingStyle (UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            BreakawayDB.UpdateUserTeam (_indexedTableItems[_keys[indexPath.Section]][indexPath.Row].TeamID, false);
            _indexedTableItems[_keys[indexPath.Section]].RemoveAt (indexPath.Row);

            tableView.DeleteRows (new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);

            if(_indexedTableItems[_keys[indexPath.Section]].Count == 0){
                tableView.DeleteSections( new NSIndexSet[] { ????? }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any tips?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteSections:withRowAnimation:)?  It's pretty clear what should be in the index set.  Do you have a specific question about NSIndexSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
tableView.DeleteSections( NSIndexSet.FromIndex (indexPath.Section), UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
```

Comment: Yes NSIndexSet.FromIndex was exactly what I was looking for...thanks!